# Regression method if dependent variable is the absolute value of a continous variable

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, unbiased-estimator, truncation

Suppose we have a dependent variable $Y$ that has normal distribution with a mean of $0$.
If I run a regression model using the absolute value of $Y$, $|Y|$, i.e. $|Y| = b_1 + b_2 X + u$, my dependent variable is actually truncated at $0$. My guess is that then OLS is not efficient anymore. What would be the usual model to use in this case? Tobit? And what would happen with the OLS estimates – are the coefficients still unbiased and only the standard errors are wrong (or OLS is inefficient) or are the coefficients biased?

Comment: It's not a question of OLS being "efficient," but rather of finding an appropriate model. The one you have written obviously is poor, because there is nothing to constrain $b_1+b_2X + u$ to be nonnegative. Moreover, in your model it is not the case that $Y$ has a normal distribution: presumably $X$ is free to vary and it is $u$ that is assumed to be normal, whence $Y$ is only conditionally normal.  You might get better results here if you were to pose your question less abstractly, in terms of the data and the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: A commonly used regression model in my research area uses the absolute value of total accruals (a part of firm's earnings) over total assets as a measure of earnings management. Before taking the absolute value, the variable can be negative or positive and usually have a mean slightly above zero. The variable is then regressed on various independent variables that are hypothesized to increase or decrease earnings management. I'm now wondering why most of the literature uses OLS when they examine these issues...

Comment: Fair enough--but your comment does appear to be quite the same as your question. You are now saying that commonly $|Y|$, and *not* $Y$, is assumed to be the response, so that when OLS is applied then implicitly $|Y|$ conditionally has a normal distribution. If the values of $|Y|$ tend to be close to zero (compared to their standard deviation) then obviously there's a problem with this model. When the model is known to be incorrect, it's difficult even to define a "bias" in any fitting procedure!